# Find the highest $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $f^{(n)}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ which for $x \in \mathbb R$: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{e^x-1}{x}, & x\neq 0\\1, & x=0\end{cases}$$ Find $\sup\left\{ n\in \mathbb N: f\text{ is }n\text{-times differentiable}\right\} $.

**My try:**
For starters, let's check if $f$ has $f^{(1)}$:
For $x\neq 0$:

- $f$ is a composite of elemental differentiable functions so also $f$ is differentiable for $x\neq 0$

For $x=0$: 
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{o(x^2)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$However we know that for $x=0$: $f(x)=1$ so $f'(x)=0\neq \frac{1}{2}$
That's why in my opinion $f$ hasn't $f'$ so also other derivative not exist. 
 However I think I can have an error because then this task is really easy.
Can you check it?

Comment: What role does $n$ play here?

Comment: For example if $f$ is $100-\text{times}$ differentiable then answer is $100$ because then $\sup(n\in \mathbb N: \text{f is differentiable})=100$

Comment: "$f$ is differentiable" has nothing to do with $n$. You should write 
$$ \sup\{ n \in\mathbb N : f \text{ is } n\text{-times differentiable} \}$$

Comment: Since we are considering natural numbers only, I think the question is to find the highest $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ such that $f^{(n)}$ exists

Comment: @RMWGNE96 yes, you have right, I used your proposition and edited my topic, thank you

Comment: @CalvinKhor yes, I'm sorry for my mistake, I corrected it

Comment: @MP3129 no problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we know that $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ in an interval around $0,$ then we can conclude that $f'(0)=0,$ but this is not the case. Let me apply the same argument to $g(x)=x$ to show you the issue.

> "Let $\alpha$ be any real number. On the one hand, $$g'(\alpha):=\lim_{x\to \alpha}\frac{g(x)-g(\alpha)}{x-\alpha}=\lim_{x\to \alpha}\frac{x-\alpha}{x-\alpha}=\lim_{x\to \alpha}1=1.$$ But on the other, we know that $g(\alpha)=\alpha,$ so since $\alpha'=0,$ then $g'(\alpha)=0\ne 1.$ Thus, $f$ is nowhere differentiable."

Rather, you have directly calculated $f'(0)=\frac12.$ Thus, $f$ is once differentiable, at least.

---

It turns out that we can do even better, using the fact that $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!},$$ so that $$e^x-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}.$$

At this point, we can fairly directly prove that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}$$ for all $x\in\Bbb R.$ Thus, $f$ is differentiable as many times as we like at $0,$ and the $n$th derivative will be $\frac1{n+1}$ for all $n.$ Since $f$ is differentiable as many times as we like everywhere else, too, then $f$ is differentiable as many times as we like everywhere.

Comment: +1 for understanding what mistake OP made

Comment: (Small typo, the $n$th derivative should be multiplied by $n!$)

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Drat! I had it right the first time....

Comment: yeah :) I think the power series of $\exp$ is a good way to remember, since $\exp'=\exp$ we know all the derivatives are 1 at 0, and the power series has $/n!$ in it

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{e^x- 1}x = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{k}}{k!}-1}x = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k}}{k!}}x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}  =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}=1+\frac{x}2+\frac{x^2}{6}+\dots$$
So this function is analytic with convergent everywhere power series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ given above. The derivatives at $0$ are $$f^{(n)}(0) = n!a_n = \frac{1}{n+1}.$$

I have no idea what you mean by

> $\text { However we know that for } x=0 : f(x)=1 \text { so } f^{\prime}(x)=0 \neq \frac{1}{2}$

Graph of $f$, some derivatives and a 5th order Taylor polynomial:
[image]

This function actually has a name, it is the  [(1,2)-Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function)
$$ f(x) = E_{1,2}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\Gamma(n+2)}.$$

For similar reasons, $\operatorname{sinc}(x):=\frac{\sin(x)}x$ only has a removable singularity at 0.

Comment: "I have no idea what you mean by" - in my sollution I get that $f'(0)=\frac{1}{2}$ but we know that $f'(0)=0$ so it is contradition and I wrote that $0 \neq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @MP3129: Actually, we don't know that $f'(0)=0,$ because it's not true. See my answer.

Comment: How do you know that $f'(0)=0?$ that's not true @MP3129 . 1/2 is correct

Comment: Maybe I have not expressed myself clearly, so I am sorry, I will explain more what I mean:for $x=0$ we know that $f(x)=1$. The derivative of the constant function is equal $0$. So if $ f $ is differentiable for $ x = 0 $ then $f'(0)=0=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)=f(0)}{x-0}$. However if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)=f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{1}{2}$ then this equality does not occur

Comment: @MP3129 Consider the function $g(x) = 1+x$. Then for $x=0$, $g(x)=1$. So "of course" $$\lim_{x\to 0}g'(0)=0?$$ but $$\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} =\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1+x - 1}{x-0} = 1 \neq 0?$$
This reasoning is faulty, $g$ is differentiable infinitely many times.  you cannot use the derivative of the constant function to help you. You should instead trust the limit definition.